# How to pass value on command line at runtime while node js running app with forever?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

When I run an app in node as 'node server.js', after calling an api it will ask to enter some value and I can enter the value on cmd. but when I run the same app with forever module I am not able to enter the value. Is there any way to do that?

ex :

Authorize this app by visiting this url:  https://someurl.com/o/oauth2/auth?dd

Enter the code from that page here:

I need to enter that value once. Please suggest

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';

var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

module.exports.auth = function (callback) {
    console.log('TOKEN_DIR', TOKEN_DIR);
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
        // Google Calendar API.
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), callback);
    });
};

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
module.exports.listEvents = function (auth, callback) {
    calendar.events.list({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, callback);
};
```

this line is aksing for the value
rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: '

Comment: You can create a file from which you can read that what you would input. Basically, change the contents of that file and read it with your node app. But please be kind to paste your code so we can see what you're aiming for.

Comment: thank for reply. I have updated the question with code